# Fill a vector of pointers with a range-based for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, ranged-loops

This code that fills a vector of pointers with the addresses of the elements of vector `v` works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    vector<int*> pv;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size(v); i++)
        pv.push_back(&(v[i]));
    for (auto i : pv)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How would I achieve the same result with a range-based for loop. I've tried code like this but it won't fill the vector of pointers correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    vector<int*> pv;
    for (auto i : v)
        pv.push_back(&i);
    for (auto i : pv)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

I'm sure I have something quite simple wrong - but haven't been able to work it out after searching around a bit.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: "I've tried code like this but it won't fill the vector of pointers correctly" What is the actual issue you're seeing?

Comment: This is probably not a good idea, in general, using either method. If you add elements to `v`, it might re-allocate the elements, and then all of the pointers would be invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the elements by reference:

```
for (auto& r : v)
    pv.push_back(&r);
```

Your original range-based for loop iterates the vector by value, making each `i` a fresh copy of each item. The expression `&i` therefore does not retrieve the address of element inside `v`.

Iterating by reference, each `r` refers to the very element inside `v`, and thus the address-of expression `&r` correctly retrieve the element's address.